# Directory Search in smartBasic

Tags: parameters, filesystems, basic

I want to implement directory search alogorithm in smartBasic. Could you advise what are the variables in this code?

```
PRINT "Current directory: ";CURRENT_DIR$()
PRINT
PRINT "Folders:"
PRINT
DIR "/" LIST DIRS a$,c
FOR n = 0 TO c-1
PRINT ,a$(n)
NEXT n
PRINT
PRINT "Files:"
PRINT
DIR "/" LIST FILES a$,c
FOR n = 0 TO c-1
PRINT ,a$(n)
NEXT n
REM What is are the variables in this code?
```

Comment: Apparently, the variables in the code are c is the counter of files, n is the for loop counter, and a$() contains the list of filenames.